# How to preserve the selected tab in Flutter upon orientation change?

Tags: flutter, orientation, state

I have an app with Tabs in Flutter and when I change orientation by rotating the device from portrait to landscape, the widget tree gets rebuilt and the state of the widgets gets reset. The effect is that the selected tab is reset back to the first tab.  I would like to prevent the state from being reset during orientation changes so that the selected tab does not also change.

In my State class I'm using the AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin and have set:

```
@override
bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
```

but that does not seem to have any effect.

Is there a way to ensure that all of my application and widget states are preserved when the device is rotated?

I can post code if that would be helpful, although I expect that this is a fairly generic question with a simple answer that I have not thought of yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add some example? It's likely something wrong in your widget tree

Comment: Ideally it is not suppose to happen. Please share your code.

Comment: Thanks... I've just recreated a trivial example and, as you suggest, it doesn't happen. I'm using scoped model and I suspect that I have my ScopedModelDescendent declared in the wrong place in the tree somewhere. I'm working now to isolate it... Once I do, I'll update this post.  Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 6):

As it turns out, after tracing all the way back through my Widget tree, I discovered that my topmost widget was declared as Stateless and I had placed a line of code in the .build method that resulted in the state of the entire app getting reset each time the widget was rebuilt - particularly on orientation changes.

To fix, I changed the widget to Stateful and moved this code into the state class into the initState method.  Once I did this, my problem was resolved because the state of this class is not affected on an orientation change.

Remi was right on the money with his comment.

A full day of coding lost, but a lot learned.  :-)

To anyone who might come across a similar problem, take a very close look at any code you place into a .build method and realize that it will get called any time the widget is rebuilt.

Still learning Flutter, but overall impressed.

Comment: Exact same mistake made, thank you very much.